# SFB 2015 & AD find users PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName and exported to CSV file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, skype-for-business

I have a CSV file with list of users in SFB on perm that doesn't have phone number assigned to them. I am trying to run the script below to collect their name and PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName and exported to CSV file. But when I ran the script it only record the last name of the CSV file. I tried *foreach-object* and *foreach* user in users but same results... Export file will only have information on list client of the list. As script keep oversight users and I end up have only one record of the last user in the imported list...

```
import-Csv  C:\temp\SKYPE_Uesers_without_phone.csv |ForEach-Object{
    Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName   -Properties PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName | select name, PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName |  Export-Csv  C:\temp\SKYPE_Uesers_without_phone_locatoin.csv  -NoTypeInformation
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
import-Csv  C:\temp\SKYPE_Uesers_without_phone.csv |ForEach-Object{
Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName  -Properties PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName | select name, PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName |  Export-Csv  C:\temp\SKYPE_Uesers_without_phone_locatoin.csv  -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Use the Append Switch:

```
import-Csv  C:\temp\SKYPE_Uesers_without_phone.csv |ForEach{
Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName  -Properties PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName | select name, PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName |  Export-Csv  C:\temp\SKYPE_Uesers_without_phone_locatoin.csv  -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

That should do your job done

Note: So with your approach , each time it is creating a new csv file and overwriting the existing one. Thats why you are having the last entry only. -Append appends the data with the existing one. If the file is not present then it will create also provided you have enough permission.

Comment: Thanks Ranadip.. issue resolved and I got the correct results:)